# PHP - Update SQL Statement mysqli database+Variables

Tags: php, html, mysqli

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 

$name = $_REQUEST['teamname']; 
$email = $_REQUEST['email']; 
$password = (md5($_REQUEST['password'])); 

$query = "UPDATE users SET email = ?,password = ? WHERE name = ?"; 
$statemnt = $conn->prepare($query); 
$statemnt->bind_param('sss',$email,$password,$name); 
$statemnt->execute(); echo $name,$email,$password; var_dump(); 
$statemnt->close(); $conn->close(); } ?>
```

managed to get the SELECT Statement figured out before this one and still having issues with the UPDATE - a form above this php snippet and is suppose to fill out $email $password and $name

```
<form method="post" action="">Team Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="teamname" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
<br>Email:<br><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"> 
<br>Password:<br><input type="text" name="password" value="">
<br><br><input type="Submit" value="Update the Record" name="Submit">
</form>
```

EDITED TO THE FOLLOWING (there is code above this part and below dont expect u want to see the rest of my html code - the bottom is what i am have trouble with):SELECT STATEMENT and var_dump is working but when i enter a password into the form it doesnt trigger the Submit and ultimately the UPDATE Statement - i have worked on it today again to no avail. pls any help would be appreciated not sure what im doing wrong - also var_dump at the bottom is outputing all of the values now

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {      
    $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET email=? , password=? WHERE team=?");
    $postedemail=$_POST['teamemail'];
    $postedpassword= $_POST['teampassword'];
    $sql->bind_param("ssi",$postedemail,$postedpassword,$_POST["mySelect"]);    
    if($sql->execute()) {
        $success_message = "Edited Successfully";
    } else {
        $error_message = "Problem in Editing Record";
    }
    var_dump($postedpassword);
    var_dump($postedemail);

}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT team, name, email, password FROM users WHERE team = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST["mySelect"]);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows === 0) exit('No rows');
while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$name = $rows['name'];
$email = $rows['email'];
$password = $rows['password'];
}

var_dump($password);
var_dump($name);
var_dump($email);
var_dump($_POST['mySelect']);
$stmt->close();
?>
<?php if(!empty($success_message)) { ?>
<div class="success message"><?php echo $success_message; ?></div>
<?php } if(!empty($error_message)) { ?>
<div class="error message"><?php echo $error_message; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
<label>NAME:</label>
<input type="text" name="teamname" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $name?>">
<label>EMAIL:</label>
<input type="text" name="teamemail" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $email?>">
<label>PASSWORD</label>
<input type="text" name="teampassword" class="txtField" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="demo-form-submit">
</form>
```

thanks

Comment: You are open to SQL Injection. This is a big NO NO. Please consider using prepared statements, PDO or sanitise your inputs manually.

Comment: MD5 is also not the most secure way to hash passwords. Consider using PHP's built in `password_hash()` function

Answer (score 0):

You have this at the begining of your script : `$selectedOption = $_POST["mySelect"];`

Nowhere in your code (especially in your `<form></form>`) I see any input named `"mySelect"`

Add this field in your form and the problem should be solved.

[`var_dump();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) helps a lot debugging.

Comment: <?php


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
$name = $_REQUEST['teamname'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$password = (md5($_REQUEST['password']));

$query = "UPDATE users SET email = ?,password = ? WHERE name = ?";
$statemnt = $conn->prepare($query);
$statemnt->bind_param('sss',$email,$password,$name);
$statemnt->execute();

echo $name,$email,$password;

var_dump();
$statemnt->close();
$conn->close();

}

?>

Comment: $email,$password,$name prints out $password and gives me 1 error
PHP Warning:  var_dump() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/atlantic/public_html/admin.php on line 201

line 201 is var_dump()

Comment: `var_dump();` expect a variable as parameter, as its name suggest, it dump the content of a variable. Did you read the documentation? I provided a link to it.

Comment: edited my message to include the part im having trouble after the above suggestions - sorry new tothe site

Comment: NULL String(32) (shows $password) NULL for the 

var_dump($name)
var_dump($password)
var_dump($email)

not sure why when i click Update button these variables are not update since its in the IF statement - trying to do this on one page with the form?